# Name of the smile when hearing an enthusiastic but naive person talks?

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

For example, a teenager telling you that one day, there will be no famine in the world, space exploration program funds won't have any limit, all conflicts will be reconciled, and humankind will live in peace and harmony.

Part of you is saying that this kid is so naive; the other part is thinking that you shouldn't burst in laugh because it's rude. The former part of you just wants to laugh, but the latter part tries hide that laugh. These two opposite directions combine into a half of a smile (usually only appearing in one side of the face). For some people, there is also a sound emitted deep inside the throat, which appears and disappears at the same time as the breath.

What is the name of the feeling you sometimes get when an enthusiastic but naive person telling?

Comment: One could say that one listened with very ambivalent feelings. As for the youngster themselves, they are probably living in *cloud cuckoo land*.

Comment: It's a lopsided smile.  It signals mixed emotions.

Comment: Do you have an expression for the emotion in your native language Ooker?

Comment: We smile a crooked smile and grunt a "aha" or "hmmm" as we listen to their pipe-dreams begrudgingly.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK unfortunately I don't know too. That's why I ask this here then will look it in the dictionary once I got the word

Comment: closevoter, please explain

Comment: It's a feeling of *deja vu*. Symptoms including rolling eyes upward.

Comment: @Drew isn't deja vu the feeling that you have seen a scene before while it is the first time you see it?

Comment: @Ooker: Whether it is actually the first time you see it or not is part of the mystery.

Comment: @Drew i mean that this is not deja vu, at least in the common meaning

Comment: @Ooker: "Deja vu" means (literally, in French) "already seen". In English, it has the special meaning of a feeling of having already seen or experienced something.

Comment: Meta question: [Why does the question about “the feeling when hearing an enthusiastic person telling their unrealistic dream” unclear?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7172/80007)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29450/discussion-between-ooker-and-drew).

Comment: While it seems unlikely that there will be a single word to cover exactly this situation, the question itself doesn't seem unclear at all to me, and I'm not sure why it was closed.

Comment: Do you have a word in your native language for the smile? That might give us a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Smirk

> a specific kind of smile, a kind of smirk, a smirk that says, 'Oh, you're an idiot! I know better. I can outwit you and control you'
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smirk)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would say that you are feeling **indulgent** toward the speaker.  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indulgent) defines "indulgent" as "willing to allow someone to have or enjoy something even though it may not be proper, healthy, appropriate, etc."

Comment: I think that's perfect. Also you could call the smile that the OP was  wondering about an "indulgent smile".

Answer (score 0):

**Empathy** may fit for "the name of that feeling".

*From Wikipedia: "Empathy" is the capacity to understand, feel or share what another person is experiencing from within the other person's frame of reference, i.e., the capacity to place oneself in another's shoes*.

Perhaps, **half a warm smile** (or "*warm half smile*" ?) for "the name of that smile".

*"Warm" then used in the sense of friendly and loving*.